# I wana have my application to fetch a html web page but i keep getting -400 whatever i try monkey c / garmin connect

Tags: rest, garmin, connectiq, monkeyc

even this exemple i found on the site of garmin has the same problem

https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/core-topics/https/

```c
import Toybox.System;
import Toybox.Communications;
import Toybox.Lang;

class JsonTransaction {
    // set up the response callback function
    function onReceive(responseCode as Number, data as Dictionary?) as Void {
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            System.println("Request Successful");                   // print success
        } else {
            System.println("Response: " + responseCode);            // print response code
        }

    }

    function makeRequest() as Void {
        var url = "https://www.garmin.com";                         // set the url

        var params = {                                              // set the parameters
            "definedParams" => "123456789abcdefg"
        };

        var options = {                                             // set the options
            :method => Communications.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_GET,      // set HTTP method
            :headers => {                                           // set headers
            "Content-Type" => Communications.REQUEST_CONTENT_TYPE_URL_ENCODED},
            // set response type
            :responseType => Communications.HTTP_RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE_URL_ENCODED
        };

        var responseCallback = method(:onReceive);                  // set responseCallback to
        // onReceive() method
        // Make the Communications.makeWebRequest() call
        Communications.makeWebRequest(url, params, options, method(:onReceive));
    }
}
```

can some one please tel me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

The return code `-400` means "Response body data is invalid for the request type." according to the SDK specification.

You are requesting a response type of `Communications.HTTP_RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE_URL_ENCODED` but in your question you state that you are expecting HTML to be returned, which almost certainly can't be parsed as URL encoded form parameters.

The SDK does not seem to support HTML response types. Even if you omit the expected response type, the server will probably still send "application/html" and the SDK states that "If the Content-Type header from the response is not one of the known HTTP_RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE_* types, an error will occur", so I guess you're out of luck.

Maybe you can try to request `HTTP_RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN` in order to get the server to return text instead of HTML, which you then could use somehow?